# I can't install PyCrypto for use AES functions

Tags: python, module, cryptography

I cannot install the PyCrypto module to use the AES method in Python 3.5.0. I tried the pip install PyCrypto command, but I get the following error: `"ERROR: The command failed with an exit state of 1:"`. When I tried `pip install pycryptodome` and `pip install pycryptodomex` everything worked, but when I tried to import `from Crypto.Cipher import AES` in python, I had an error that Crypto did not detect.

Comment: Can you add your operating system and python distro?

Comment: You can install pycryptodomex and pycrypto, but not pycryptodome and pycrypto, and not pycryptodome, pycryptodomex, and pycrypto.

Comment: And, i have windows, i tryed all methods.Wht should i do?

Comment: Please always clearly and fully indicate the errors that you're receiving!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in compatibility between the two. I had the same issue when I installed both pycrypto and pycryptodome. So, I uninstalled pycrypto and it worked like a charm.

```
sudo pip3 uninstall pycrypto
```

Comment: Hi! I have windows. I tryed but falled.

Answer (score 0):

i just upgrade pip and tried `pip install pycryptodome`. And all working! Thank's everyone!